# move an element to another element or create a new one if it does not exist using xslt-3

Tags: xslt-3.0

using xslt 3, i need to take all content elements' values, and move them to the title elements (if the title elements already exist in a record, they need to be appended with a separator like -) i now have inputted my real data, since the below solution does not solve the problem when implemented to something like:
example input:

```
<data>
       <RECORD ID="31365">
            <no>25099</no>
            <seq>0</seq>
            <date>2/4/2012</date>
            <ver>2/4/2012</ver>
            <access>021999</access>
            <col>GS</col>
            <call>889</call>
            <pr>0</pr>
            <days>0</days>
            <stat>0</stat>
            <ch>0</ch>
            <title>1 title</title>
            <content>1 content</content>
            <sj>1956</sj>
                    </RECORD>
        <RECORD ID="31366">
            <no>25100</no>
            <seq>0</seq>
            <date>2/4/2012</date>
            <ver>2/4/2012</ver>
            <access>022004</access>
            <col>GS</col>
            <call>8764</call>
            <pr>0</pr>
            <days>0</days>
            <stat>0</stat>
            <ch>0</ch>
            <sj>1956</sj>
            <content>1 title</content>
                    </RECORD>
</data>

    expected output:
<data>
                        <RECORD ID="31365">
                <no>25099</no>
                <seq>0</seq>
                <date>2/4/2012</date>
                <ver>2/4/2012</ver>
                <access>021999</access>
                <col>GS</col>
                <call>889</call>
                <pr>0</pr>
                <days>0</days>
                <stat>0</stat>
                <ch>0</ch>
                <title>1 title - 1 content</title>
                <sj>1956</sj>
                        </RECORD>
            <RECORD ID="31366">
                <no>25100</no>
                <seq>0</seq>
                <date>2/4/2012</date>
                <ver>2/4/2012</ver>
                <access>022004</access>
                <col>ΓΣ</col>
                <call>8764</call>
                <pr>0</pr>
                <days>0</days>
                <stat>0</stat>
                <ch>0</ch>
                <sj>1956</sj>
                <title>1 title</title>
                        </RECORD>
<data>
```

with my attempt, i did not manage to move the elements, i just got an empty line where the content element existed, so please add the removal of blank lines in the suggested solution.

i believe the removal of blank lines could be fixed with the use of

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is the following template. It uses XSLT-3.0 content value templates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0" expand-text="true">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />   <!-- Remove space between elements -->    

    <xsl:template match="RECORD">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <title>{title[1]}{if (title[1]) then ' - ' else ''}<xsl:value-of select="content" separator=" " /></title>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except (title,content)" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's output is as desired.
If you want to separate the `<content>` elements with a `-`, too, you can simplify the core `<title>` expression to

```
<xsl:value-of select="title|content" separator=" - " />
```

**EDIT:**
All I changed was replacing `chapter` with `RECORD`, and it's working fine with Saxon-HE 9.9.1.4J. The only difference in the output is that the `title` element is always at the first position, but that shouldn't matter. I also added a directive to remove space between elements.

Comment: could you please update the above solution, so as not truncate all other elements than title and content?

Comment: Done.  Hope that will fix the problem.

Comment: again  get not any result, i have updated my question with the real data i have, thank you

Comment: i am using saxon he 9.9, something is not working on my side...

Comment: Updated the template again.

Comment: I just noticed: your XSLT fiddle above does not use my answer at all, so it's no wonder it doesn't work. New fiddle is https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCzsQ/1